# Degree of regularity of a Markov chain

Tags: reference-request, probability-theory, markov-chains

A Markov chain with transition matrix $P$ is termed *regular* if for some $n$, all entries of $P^n$ are positive.

Is there a known notion of *degree of regularity* quantified in terms of how soon all entries are positive? That is, a Markov chain with transition matrix $P$ would be considered *more regular* than a Markov chain with transition matrix $Q$ if $P^n$ has positive entries but $Q^m$ only has positive entries for $m>n$.

Comment: This would precisely capture the length of the longest path between all shortest paths in the markov chain graph

Comment: Sounds like you've just defined such a notion.  Is there something you want to know about it?

Comment: @D.W. Yes I suppose so. I’m wondering if this notion has already been established in the literature. I’d like to read up on it if so.

Comment: If im not mistaken this is the diameter of the graph representing the merkov chain

Comment: This would be something well known in the literature of graphs, but i don't know how useful it is in the literature of markov chains